# Xcode git Beanstalk authentication required

Tags: xcode, git, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, beanstalk-svn

Since late Xcode 4.3.x and continuing into 4.4+ the git service provided by Beanstalkapp.com no longer works with Xcode. Xcode won't list the remote repos, and therefore can't push to them. I just noticed that when trying to set up a new repo it now says "Authentication Required" which is much more helpful than the nothing but failure I was getting before. Git to beanstalk works perfectly fine from the command line, it's just remote based actions in Xcode that fail. Beanstalk uses an SSH key to auth the user, which is set and works fine per the command line success. It *used* to work in Xcode many versions ago.

Does anyone have any thoughts about how to fix this? I presume it's a compatibility issue with the git that is embedded in Xcode, but don't have any more thoughts than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this ultimately by using another git client (tower) to modify the repo configuration oddly. The push URL syntax had to be modified slightly, which makes no sense a) why it would suddenly stop working, b) why it would need to be modified and c) why I couldn't modify it properly in Xcode and d) why it still worked fine from the command line... Chalking it up as a fluke probably related to my password or something obscure like that. Apologies for not having the fixed syntax at hand but it's buried in the config somewhere and I can't seem to figure out how to get to it through xcode or tower.